# How do i attach my database to the local SQL Server in my setup project

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Here is how i proceed :

1. I Creating an empty database is SSMS 2008 (Ex : myDB.mdf)
2. I create a new project in VS2010
3. I add EF4 Model ( the edmx file)
4. I design my model (entities & associations...)
5. I Generate the database from the model (targeting myDB.mdf)
6. I Start coding...

i know that the database i am using is attached to the local SQL Server instance ! (so basically the database can be in any physical location on the machine as long as it is attached to the SQL instance under the same name, this is what i am looking for...)

But my problem is that : every time i deploy my application for a client using the Setup project, i need also to install SSMS and copy an empty database (myDB.mdf) to the SQL Server and attach it ?

I'm sure that this is not the right approach, so could you please show me how can i : automate the copying, attaching of the database ?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30440/how-do-i-attach-a-database-in-sql-server

Comment: good answer, does this mean that i have to Script the creation & attaching of my database into SQL Script and execute it at the first lunching of the application so it can create the database and attach ?